# Return object object, but its not null

Tags: javascript, power-automate-desktop

I have this code:

```
// Select all date elements that are not disabled
let availableDates = document.querySelectorAll('.calendar__date-container:not(.is-disabled) .calendar__date');

// Log or process the available dates
availableDates.forEach(date => {
    console.log(date.textContent); // Replace with your processing logic
});
```

Which does work in console on edge, but if I try to put it in Power Automate Desktop, it just returns object object.

I have tried adding a new return line as the following:

```
return JSON.stringify(date.textContent);
```

But still the same. I can read that it might be because its an object, but can't get it to return the values..

btw, tried this https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/foreach-object, with some help from chatGPT, but still no luck, again it does seem to work in console.

```
  let availableDates = document.querySelectorAll('.calendar__date-container:not(.is-disabled) .calendar__date');
  let datesArray = [];

  availableDates.forEach(date => {
    datesArray.push(date.textContent);
  });

  return JSON.stringify(datesArray.join(', ')); // Replace with your processing logic
```

Comment: try  data.innerText

Comment: I tried innertext, but still object object. 
Also I just tried console.log for availableDates, and I can see the date in InnerText.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual problem code; there's no point including only the code that works. Also, when you say _"it just returns object object"_, what is _it_?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the api of document is not good running in  power-automate-desktop,try to use js create dom just like vue and react.

```js
const dataList = [{
  textContent: 'xxx',
  disable: ture
}, {
  textContent: 'xxx',
  disable: false
}]
render()

function render() {
  const container = document.querySelector('.calendar__date-container')
  const html = dataList.reduce((pre, item) =>
      return pre += `<div class="calendar__date">${item.textContent}</div>`

    },
    '')
container.innerHTML = html
}

// Log or process the available dates
dataList.forEach(date => {
  if (!data.disable) {
    console.log(date.textContent); // Replace with your processing logic
  }
});
```